# DATALAB does not start correctly

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

In try to get Datalab running on my iMAC

I get until

~ docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080" -v "${HOME}:/content"    -e "PROJECT_ID=xxxxxx"    gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local

I put my project ID for the xxxxxx

From https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at d2c492f Merge pull request #7 from googledatalab/feature/stackdriver_monitoring
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
{"name":"app","hostname":"xxxxxxxxx","pid":62,"level":30,"msg":"Starting DataLab server at http://localhost:8080","time":"2016-08-27T21:00:16.848Z","v":0}

I tried then to look at the localhost:8080 but nothing goes. I think it is stuck somewhere

Can somebody please
Peter

Answer (score 0):

From the [Datalab quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local) documentation, try connecting to http://localhost:8081 rather than http://localhost:8080. The console output has improved in the next version that will be published soon.

In the next version, the console will display the following text:

```
Starting Datalab in silent mode, for debug output, rerun with an additional '-e DATALAB_DEBUG=true' argument
Open your browser to http://localhost:8081/ to connect to Datalab.
```

Comment: I tried the port 8081, but nothing works. Is this JSON like output really the only message I can expect thta confirms that the server was started?

Comment: the folder datalab with the 'normal'? datastructure including notebooks are nicely present on my iMAC. What's the difference when I would open the notebooks just with standard jupyter notebook?

Comment: There is a known issue where certain users may see a blank page when visiting http://localhost:8081 . If you see a blank page, try the temporary workaround documented in the comments in [Datalab Github Issue #950](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/950).  A proper fix for this issue will in the next version that will be published soon. If this doesn't resolve your issue, please create a new issue in the [Datalab Github project](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/new) with the full console output.

Comment: Anthonios, I don't see a blan page but the browser does see the server. I will put the details as per recommendation. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. the browser cannot reach the server as there is no server up and running

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue on my iMac. The console output will be very helpful in tracking down the root cause. Please let me know once you have the full console output.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues is having the same problem it is working perfectly fine in our other systems except his. Please update the thread if there was an update to this problem.